# How to get the first record from a list in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get a list of records where the GLOBALID is unique based on MAX of column Final

e.g. data

```
GLOBALID   FIRST  SECOND  FINAL
-------------------------------
00345       867    --      8976
00345       989    567     5674
00356       765    554     5658
00359       ---    543     7567
```

Result should be..

```
GLOBALID  FIRST  SECOND  FINAL
-------------------------------
00345      867    --     8976
00356      765    554    5658
00359      ---    543    7567
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need a huge number of those messy `<br>` and `&nbsp;` tags, either!

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
  select globalid, max(final) as m_final
  from your_table
  group by globalid
) t2 on t1.globalid = t2.globalid and t1.final = t2.m_final
```

Comment: Thanks you! That was extremely fast response.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*
from (
  select yt.*, 
         max(final) over (partition by globalid) as m_final
  from your_table
) t1
where t1.final = t1.m_final;
```

You still might get more than one row per `globalid` if the "max. value" occurs more than once. To prevent that, you can use `row_number()`

```
select t1.*
from (
  select yt.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by globalid order by final desc) as rn
  from your_table
) t1
where rn = 1;
```